# Measuring electron spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, electrons, quantum-spin

How do experimental physicists measure the angular momentum for the spin of an electron? A paper about an experiment would be helpful. Alternatively, how was the electron spin value of $\hbar/2$ determined?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment may be helpful.